# Getting OOM issue while running ruta script with large texts

Tags: uima, ruta

Sample script:

```
DocumentAnnotation{-> RETAINTYPE(SPACE,BREAK)};


((NUM (SPECIAL NUM)?)|EntityType{FEATURE("entityType", "amount")})
(COMMA|SPACE|BREAK)*
((W|NUM) (SPACE | PERIOD)?)*
(COMMA|SPACE|BREAK)*
(((W|NUM) (SPACE | PERIOD)?)*(COMMA|SPACE|BREAK)*)
((EntityType+{FEATURE("entityType", "location_indicator")} | (NUM{REGEXP(".....")}
("-" NUM{REGEXP("....")})?))
(COMMA|SPACE|BREAK)*)+
{-> MARK(EntityType,1,8)};




NUM+
// 123-1
(SPECIAL NUM+)?
SPACE*
// Street lane road
((W|NUM) (SPACE | PERIOD)?)*
(COMMA|SPACE)*
// City
(W SPACE?)+
(COMMA|SPACE)*
// state
(W SPACE?)+
(COMMA|SPACE)*
// pincode
NUM
(COMMA|SPACE)*
W?{REGEXP("(?i)(USA|US|CANADA)") ->MARK(EntityType,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)};
```

We are getting OOM issues randomly but it happens only in prod environment we are not able to reproduce locally. Any clue if script is the real problem. Below is the stack trace from thread dump apart from this we don't have access to actual text which caused this

```
"EMAIL-Thread-1105" Id=37590 in RUNNABLE
BlockedCount : 328, BlockedTime : -1, WaitedCount : 48354, WaitedTime : -1
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElementMatch.enforceUpdate(ComposedRuleElementMatch.java:57)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElementMatch.enforceUpdate(ComposedRuleElementMatch.java:57)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElementMatch.setInnerMatches(ComposedRuleElementMatch.java:63)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElementMatch.copy(ComposedRuleElementMatch.java:138)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElementMatch.copy(ComposedRuleElementMatch.java:35)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElementMatch.copy(ComposedRuleElementMatch.java:131)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.continueMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:208)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.continueOwnMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:370)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.fallbackContinue(ComposedRuleElement.java:474)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.continueMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:233)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.continueOwnMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:370)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.fallbackContinue(ComposedRuleElement.java:474)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.continueMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:233)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.continueOwnMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:370)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.fallbackContinue(ComposedRuleElement.java:474)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.continueMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:233)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.continueOwnMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:370)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.fallbackContinue(ComposedRuleElement.java:474)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.continueMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:233)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.continueOwnMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:370)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.fallbackContinue(ComposedRuleElement.java:474)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.continueMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:233)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.continueOwnMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:370)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.fallbackContinue(ComposedRuleElement.java:474)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.continueMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:233)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.continueOwnMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:370)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.fallbackContinue(ComposedRuleElement.java:474)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.continueMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:233)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.continueOwnMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:370)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.fallbackContinue(ComposedRuleElement.java:474)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.continueMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:233)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.continueOwnMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:370)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.fallbackContinue(ComposedRuleElement.java:474)
    at
```

Comment: our ruta version is 2.8.1

Comment: If you are comfortable building a pre-release version of Ruta from source, you could check if the changes that have accumulated in the "main-v2" branch resolve your problem. If they do, please post a message to the uima-users mailing list to let the developers know. Greetings from the UIMA team.

Comment: we are not able to find the root cause yet because this issue is not reproducible in lower environments

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your OOM is caused by an endless loop in which helper annotations are created. These annotations probably consume the memory. This loop could be caused by a special combination of characters or annotation which do not occur in your dev setting. The OOM could also be caused by the large rule containing many disjunctive rule elements.

In the latest release, several of these problems have already been fixed. I highly recommend upgrading to Ruta 3.2.0. Some of them are also fixed in the main-v2 branch.

An OOM can be worst case for an application and an exception may be preferred. You could restrict the number of allowed matches of rules and rule element with the parameters PARAM_MAX_RULE_MATCHES and PARAM_MAX_RULE_ELEMENT_MATCHES. This can help to ensure the stability of your application, but it is not a solution.

If updating the Ruta version is not an option, you can avoid the problem by refactoring your rules. I would recommend removing the disjunctive rule elements and split the rules into several smaller rules. Then, you can also avoid the stacked quantifiers. I would also recommend separating the whitespace sensitive parts from the whitespace insensitive parts.

Comment: 1. we are not able  upgradeto to Ruta 3.x because we have to upgrade uimaj-core also and to do that we need an stable version of cleartk-ml (which is not working with uima 3.x). 
2.  using PARAM_MAX_RULE_MATCHES , PARAM_MAX_RULE_ELEMENT_MATCHES we are not sure what numer will be good enough.
3. if possible can you please suggest an improved version for above script it will really help.
4. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Also getting a new build from main-v2 is also not possible because we can only use ga versions which are available directly in mvn repository.